# Scattering in (pseudo-)Riemannian spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

I will ask my question in a broad way, leaving a lot of freedom for answers.

Suppose that we have a (pseudo-)Riemannian space $(M,g)$ and we fix some ball-like domain $B \subset M$. Suppose you are given a function $f$ which maps every $(x,v_x)$ ($x \in \partial B$, $v_x \in T_x M$) to a $y \in B$ such that the geodesic emanating from $x$ with speed $v_x$ has its first intersection with $\partial B$ (beyond $x$) at $y$.

**Q1**: Does the function $f$, together with the induced metric on $\partial B$, determine $g\left.\right|_B$ up to isometry? What conditions must $f$ satisfy in order for such a metric $g$ to exist?

**Q2**: What other information, "extractible from $\partial B$", about geodesics can lead us to determine $g$ in the interior of $B$? (Perhaps knowing the length of all geodesics between to intersection points may help?)

I've also asked the question here (or at least a similar question), without any response: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611028/scattering-in-riemannian-spaces

Comment: I am not familiar with the terminology "ball-like domain". Can you explain what exactly that entails? Also you may want to restrict to dimensions $\geq 2$. When $d = 1$ the questions are trivial but in the wrong way to the way you want.

Comment: In similar spirit you also have trivial counter examples in $d \geq 2$ if you take $B$ to be a cylinder $\Sigma\times [-1,1]$ for some closed Riemannian manifold $\Sigma$. Give $B$ the metric $g_\Sigma + f(s) \mathrm{d}s^2$. As long as $\int \sqrt{f(s)} \mathrm{d}s$ is a fixed constant, the scattering map is independent of $f$. But of course these are all isometric (by a simple change of coordinates in the interior), so perhaps you want to exclude that by requiring that the metric $g|_B$ is determined uniquely up to diffeomorphisms $B\to B$.

Comment: Yes, of course I mean unique up to isometry (I was looking for a short formulation for the question, leaving out things like that). As for a ball-like domain $B$, what about there existing a diffeomorphism $f$ from $B$ to the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $f$ need not be an isometry but whose length changes are bounded below by some factor $c>0$ and above by some factor $C>c$. Also $\partial B$ ought to be a smooth codimension-1 manifold of $M$

Comment: *codimension-1 **sub**manifold